# What is a thread-safe DBM library in C?

Tags: c, thread-safety, pthreads, dbm

Does anyone know about a [thread-safe](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) [DBM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dbm)-like library with a C API?

This is: a persistent hash-table that is thread-safe.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: D'oh! It seems [Tokyo Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/spex-en.html) fixed-length hashtables fit the bill!!

Answer (score 0):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/index.html) [is threadsafe](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6). It is also [in the public domain](http://www.sqlite.org/copyright.html).

Comment: I believe SQLite is a transactional SQL database engine and not a persistent hash-table. Berkeley DB (sometimes dbm) is an example of a database engine that uses a hashing scheme.